# Delimiter for Encrypted Value to be saved in database

Tags: java, encryption, delimiter

I want to save encrypted value (Java) in the database with key alias in the same column. What is the best delimiter which can be used which does not mess up with encrypted value and key version?

Comment: I'd recommend add a new column to your table for your  key alias  instead of creating some strange logic to split your column based on a delimiter.

Comment: why is that ? what if we have multiple column which can be updated by different independent queries?